# How image pixels are treated in web browsers?

Tags: css, image, browser, pixel

The W3C documentation states the following:

> Pixels (px) are relative to the viewing device. For low-dpi devices, 1px is one device pixel (dot) of the display. For printers and high resolution screens 1px implies multiple device pixels.

This kind of makes sense for standard elements, like divs and tables. If the screen has a greater pixel density, more real pixels are reserved for a CSS pixel, in order to keep the actual element dimension roughly equal on all the screens regardless their density. In this sense, CSS pixels can be seen as a pseudo-absolute length measure.

But what about images? I know it's bad practice to let the browser to resize images. But then how source image's pixels are treated? I suppose it can't be the same as other elements, otherwise I would get a low resolution image on high-density screen, given that more device pixels are assigned to a single image pixel.

Answer (score 0):

If the resolution of an image is lower than the resolution of the screen, the graphic card will add pixels to make the image fill the pixels needed.

So if your image has the same resolution than your screen, each pixels of the image is rendered in each pixels of your screen.

But if your image has a lower resolution than your screen, and if the graphic card would not do the job, your image would appear smaller because it has not enought pixels to fill your actual screen resolution.

[image]

As your can see, the graphic card will always force a middle color, which is a medium between your two colors.

Obviously, if you image if a full black pixels, the middle color of black-black is black, so the image will not appear stretched.

Comment: As per your answer, browsers perform some kind of interpolation when image resolution doesn't fit the screen. Which is what we want to avoid to prevent image degradation. It it was this way, I would have to provide a different image for each screen density.

Comment: Yes, that's why some WordPress theme asks for an additionnal Retina-ready image, (so twice the image size) with your original image to have a perfect ratio and not force the GC to stretch the pixels.